# Getting #n/a when changing value field settings in Pivot table using vba

Tags: vba, pivot-table, excel-2016

I have a use case where I filter the column values in a pivot and then change the value field settings of the pivot table. I am creating the pivot table and the sheet every time while deleting the previous one. My problem is that I am unable to get one column to reflect in the pivot but the values are correct in the grand total. My code is below:

```
  Sub createPivotandFilter()
    'Declare Variables
    Dim PSheet As Worksheet
    Dim DSheet As Worksheet
    Dim PCache As PivotCache
    Dim PTable As PivotTable
    Dim PRange As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim pf As PivotField
    Dim PItems As PivotItem

    'Insert a New Blank Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets("PivotTable").Delete
    Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTable"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Set PSheet = Worksheets("PivotTable")
    Set DSheet = Worksheets("Data_TB Detail")

    'Define Data Range
    LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

    'Define Pivot Cache
    Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
    CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(3, 1), _
    TableName:="VariancePivot")

    'Insert Blank Pivot Table
    Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
    (TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="VariancePivot")

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("VariancePivot")
        .InGridDropZones = True
        .RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow
    End With

    'Insert Column Fields
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("VariancePivot").PivotFields("Period")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 1
    End With

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("VariancePivot").PivotFields("LE")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 2
    End With

    'Insert Row Fields
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("VariancePivot").PivotFields("Mapped up 1st  level")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
    End With

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("VariancePivot").PivotFields("Account")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 2
    End With

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("VariancePivot").PivotFields("Description")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 3
    End With

    'Insert Data Field
     With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("VariancePivot").PivotFields("USD")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Position = 1
      .Function = xlSum
      .NumberFormat = "#,##0"
      .Name = "Sum of USD"
      .Calculation = xlDifferenceFrom
       .BaseField = "Period"
       .BaseItem = "Jun 30,2018"
      End With

    'adding the filter
    Set PTable = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("VariancePivot")
    Set pf = PTable.PivotFields("Period")
    PTable.RefreshTable

    temp = pf.PivotItems.Count
    For i = 1 To temp
        If pf.PivotItems(i).Value = "Jun 30,2018" Or pf.PivotItems(i).Value =   "Sep 30,2018" Then
            pf.PivotItems(i).Visible = True
        Else
            pf.PivotItems(i).Visible = False
        End If
    Next

    End Sub
```

A screenshot of the result:
[image]

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any errors if you remove `On Error Resume Next`?

Comment: yes. It gives out of memory error sometimes